# Sort list of lists based on nth integer in list name in R?

Tags: r, list

Say I have a list of lists with list names that differ by the last integer in the name.

```
gfit10_3 <- list(1,1,1)
gfit10_1 <- list(1,1,1)
gfit10_2 <- list(1,1,1)
gfit10_10 <- list(1,1,1)

list1 <- list(gfit10_3=gfit10_3, gfit10_1=gfit10_1, gfit10_2=gfit10_2, gfit10_10=gfit10_10)
```

How do I order the list in ascending order based on the list name so the list would look like this?

```
list1 <- list(gfit10_1, gfit10_2, gfit10_3, gfit10_10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this alternative:

```
new_order <- order(as.numeric(sub(".*_(\\d+)", "\\1",names(list1))))
list1[new_order]
```

The list would be sorted by this order:

```
> names(list1)[new_order]
[1] "gfit10_1"  "gfit10_2"  "gfit10_3"  "gfit10_10"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a lookbehind `?<=_` in  `regexpr`.

```
ord <- order(as.integer(regmatches(names(list1), regexpr('(?<=_)(\\d+)', names(list1), perl=TRUE))))
```

```
names(list1[ord])
# [1] "gfit10_1"  "gfit10_2"  "gfit10_3"  "gfit10_10"
```

Comment: note the order in your asnwer does not match the order  wanted by the OP

Comment: @JilberUrbina Seems I've pasted sth wrong, fixed thx!